# How do I pass an arbitrary list of arguments on the command line in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

I know how to pass single and named arguments on the command line to a Perl 6 script, but how do I pass an arbitrary list of arguments?

For example,

```
script.pl6 fileA.txt fileB.txt
```

and then run it with

```
script.pl6 fileC.txt fileD.txt .. fileZ.txt
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The raw commandline arguments can be found in `@*ARGS`.

You can also use a sub `&MAIN` with a slurpy parameter, ie

```
sub MAIN(*@args) { ... }
```

Note that this will reject invocations that pass flags. If you want to capture those as well, use

```
sub MAIN(*@args, *%flags) { ... }
```

Comment: Is there any way to use slurpy with `:`? That's what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: A comma is missing in second code block, before *%flags.

Comment: @CIAvash: thanks; @CyberSkull: what do you mean by *slurpy with `:`*?

Comment: @CIAvash I mean with named parameters, like "--list1" in the command line.

Comment: @CyberSkull As @Christoph mentioned you can access them with %flags(when you use *%flags as MAIN parameter). So for example "--list1" can be accessed with `%flags<list1>`. You can also add it specifically as a MAIN parameter like this: `sub MAIN (:$list1, *@args, *%flags) {...}`